# Enable Cache On Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage, cache-control, azure-cdn

I am setting up Azure CDN, and having trouble setting the Cache-Control header.

I used Cloudberry Explorer to setup a sync between my server folders and the CDN.  This is working well.   All my files were copied to the CDN with no problem.

Under Tools > Http Headers > Edit Http Header I set the value for Cache-Control to be: public,max-age=604800

However, this does not appear to be having any effect (according to both Fiddler and Page Speed).

Any tips on setting the Cache-Control header for the Azure CDN would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check if the `Cache-Control` property on the blob is being set correctly? You can verify it either programmatically by fetching blob properties or another 3rd party tool like `Azure Explorer` from Cerebrata or `Azure Storage Explorer` from CodePlex.

Comment: Using Azure Explorer from Cerebrata it doesn't appear to be set. :-(

Comment: It looks like an issue with Cloudberry Explorer then. I don't think headers are being set by the tool. You may want to reach out to their support or use another tool. Essentially the cache-control header property on the blob must be set. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue myself and needed to update the `Cache-Control` header on thousands of files. To prevent caching issues in sites, I re-deploy these files with every release to a new path.

I was able to patch together some different suggestions online and ultimately landed on the following solution, which I currently use for deploying one of my production apps.

You need two files, and the script assumes they're in the same directory on your computer:

- A text file with a listing of the files in the container (see example below)
- The PowerShell script

---

### The Text File (file-list.txt)

The file should be in the example format below with the full file path as deployed to the CDN container. Note this uses forward slashes, and should not include the container name since it will be included in the script. The name of this text file will be included in the PowerShell script below.

```
v12/app/app.js
v12/app/app.min.js
v12/app/app.min.js.map
v12/app/account/signup.js
v12/app/account/signup.min.js
... (and so on)
```

---

### The Script (cdn-cache-control.ps1)

The full script is below. You'll need to replace the constants like `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME`, `STORAGE_KEY`, and you may need to update the path to the Azure SDK DLL if you have a different version. There are also 2 possible implementations of `$blobClient`; I repurposed some of this code from a source online, and the un-commented one works for me.

The key difference between what I have here and what you'll find online is the inclusion of `$blob.FetchAttributes()`. Without explicitly calling this method, a majority of the blob properties like `Content-Type`, Last Modified Date, and others will be loaded into memory as empty/default values, then when `$blob.SetProperties()` is called these empty values will blow away the existing ones in the CDN, causing files to load without a `Content-Type` among other things.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll"

$accountName = "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME"
$accountKey = "STORAGE_KEY"
$blobContainerName = "STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"

$storageCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey -ArgumentList $accountName,$accountKey
$storageAccount = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount -ArgumentList $storageCredentials,$true
#$blobClient = $storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
$blobClient = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudStorageAccountStorageClientExtensions]::CreateCloudBlobClient($storageAccount)

$cacheControlValue = "max-age=31556926"

echo "Setting cache control: $cacheControlValue"

Get-Content "file-list.txt" | foreach {
    $blobName = "$blobContainerName/$_".Trim()
    $blob = $blobClient.GetBlobReference($blobName)
    $blob.FetchAttributes() 
    $blob.Properties.CacheControl = $cacheControlValue
    $blob.SetProperties()
    echo $blobName
}
```

It was tricky to find information about mass-setting the `Cache-Control` header but I've run this script for multiple production releases with great success. I've verified the configuration of the header as well, and routinely run Google's PageSpeed Insights against my site to verify.

Comment: This looks like it has to make HTTP requests for every file. How many files do you run this against? I've got several hundred thousand.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek I'd guess several hundred, maybe low thousands (mostly third-party scripts so hard to say.) Not sure what to recommend with that many. :/